# Java 8, Stream - Find the count of strings that have sum of digits more than 10

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I'm learning java 8 and I wrote code that finds the count of collection element, which strings contain digits with sum more than 10.

For example:

"56abc" - this string contains sum of 11 and satisfies the condition of the task

"56" - this string also contains sum of 11 and satisfies the condition of the task

"12sdf" - this string contains sum of 3 and does not satisf the condition of the task

My code works, but I think it's too large and bad. Is there a way to make it better? Thanks!

```
List<String> listString = Arrays.asList("83d","349d", "12");
Stream<String> s1 = listString.stream(); //get stream of string elements
Stream<IntStream> s2 = s1.map(x->x.chars()); //get stream of chars
Stream<Stream<Integer>> s3 = s2.map(IntStream::boxed); //convert IntStream to Stream<Integer> 
Stream<Stream<String>> s4 = s3.map(x->x.map(val->String.valueOf((char)val.intValue()))); //convert Stream<Integer> to Stream<String>
Stream<Stream<String>> s5 = s4.map(x->x.filter(val->val.matches("\\d+"))); //filter chars, that is not a digit
Stream<Stream<Integer>> s6 = s5.map(x->x.map(Integer::parseInt)); //convert String to Integer
Stream<Integer> s7 = s6.map(x->x.mapToInt(val->val).sum()); //find sum of digits
Stream<Integer> s8 = s7.filter(val->val>10); //filter sums that is less of 10
long count = s8.count(); //get count of elements
System.out.println("count = "+count);
```

Comment: Abstraction as visible - **find the count of strings** for those **strings which have the sum of digits more than 10**. You would find yourself in a much better place dealing with object-oriented programming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, replace a `non-digit` character with an empty string. then in the filter by converting each string to `IntStream` and perform `sum()` operation you can calculate the sum of the numeric characters and at the end count the result.

```
listString.stream()
            .map(s -> s.replaceAll("\\D", ""))
            .filter(s -> s.chars().map(c -> Character.getNumericValue(c)).sum() > 10)
            .count();
```

or even better performance and more readable way suggested by Holger.

```
listString.stream()
           .filter(s ->s.chars()
              .filter(Character::isDigit)
              .map(Character::getNumericValue)
              .sum() > 10) 
           .count();
```

Comment: There is no reason to perform an expensive string replacement operation here. It’s not even what should come into your mind first when you just want to count matching elements. Just use a straight-forward `listString.stream() .filter(s -> s.chars().filter(Character::isDigit).map(Character::getNumericValue).sum() > 10) .count()`

Comment: @Holger, Thanks for your great comment. I added it to the answer.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, it defeats the purpose to assign each intermediate `Stream` to a variable. Just chain all the method calls.

Second of all, you can achieve the same result which much fewer steps.

For each `IntStream`, filter out all the characters that are not between '0' and '9', map the remaining characteres to their numeric values and sum them.

```
List<String> listString = Arrays.asList("83d","349d", "12");
long count = listString.stream()
                       .map(x->x.chars())
                       .filter(x -> x.filter(i -> i >= '0' && i <= '9')
                                     .map(i -> i - '0')
                                     .sum() > 10)
                       .count();
System.out.println("count = " + count);
```

Comment: Why do you put `x->x.chars()` in the `map` method? It'd be much more understandable if it was in the `filter` method as well.

Comment: *Opinion* - Without abstraction, this is still a decent compromise on readability and extensibility!

Comment: @Naman In which regard in this a) more readable or b) more extensible than just doing `x.chars()` in the `filter` step, where all other inner stream operations are chained?

Comment: @Holger I didn't completely get what your question is. But assuming you meant *In which regard **is** this*, I was of the opinion that finding out the sum of digits of a String (or even checking if that is greater than the desired value) could have been abstracted out in another method to better reuse. Hence the use of words *decent compromise* in my previous comment.

Comment: @Naman there was no context to understand what you meant with “abstraction” or which “compromise” you were talking about, so it seemed like you were referring to the previous comment.